# How do I force GNU "barcode" to honor the page size I specify on the command line?

Tags: barcode, postscript

history:
I am trying to get GNU "barcode" to produce bar codes that I can add to pick lists, and work orders. I am trying to create the bar-codes as small as the physical labels that we use in the warehouse (2.5"x0.75") using the following command:

```
#barcode -b 'TEXTTOENCODE' -c -e code39 -u in -g 2.5x0.75 -u in -p 2.5x0.75 > bc.ps
```

problem:
No matter what page size parameters I use, I only seem to be able to produce US Letter size documents.

When I open the resulting file (in KDE Document Viewer) the file properties are reported as: 'US Letter, Portrait (216 × 279 mm)' as seen below:
[KDE Document Viewer - Sample Barcode image with picture properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHnto.png)

GNU barcode version below:

```
# barcode --version
barcode frontend (GNU barcode) 0.98
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong, are welcome.

Thanks,
'Skye

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong, it's just that `barcode` uses an obsolete  DSC comment to declare paper size, which isn't recognized by the PS viewer.  Maybe try using option -E? This will crop the document to just the bar code.

Comment: Thank you. This has corrected the issue I was having.

Comment: @angus, turn your comment into an actual Answer, then a) you get points, and b) this question no longer looks as if it is Unanswered.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt: OK, done.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing nothing wrong, it's just that `barcode` uses an obsolete DSC comment to declare paper size, which isn't recognized by the PS viewer. Maybe try using option -E? This will crop the document to just the bar code.